# How to solve $\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{3x + \sqrt{x^2}}}$?

Tags: functions, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{3x + \sqrt{x^2}}}$$

How to solve the above indefinite integration? I am trying this question by taking out $x^2$ from the root sign. Now when I am taking out $x^2$ from the root sign the value will be $|x|$. Now when $x > 0$, $|x|$ will be $+x$ and when $x < 0$, $|x|$ will be $-x$. But in case of this indefinite integration I am confused which value to take, $x$ or $-x$, because there is no limit given for $x$. Also I am thinking to write this integration as $\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{3x+x\cdot \operatorname{sgn}(x)}}}$. But I don't know how to approach further. Please help me out with this question.

Comment: When x<0, then 3x+|x|=2x. But if x<0, 2x is also less than 0. This means that taking its square root will not be a real number anymore. So, the integral will not be defined when x<0. Also, you can see that the integral is not defined when x=0. Therefore you only have to check for x>0

Comment: Feel free to familiarize yourself with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help make your question a little more legible.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Soham.